# What is entropy mean in this context?

Tags: mining-theory, proof-of-work

"The Bitcoin nonce forms part of the block header, which is used by miners to provide entropy as part of the Proof of Work process, to try and find a hash meeting the difficulty requirement."

Quote taken from the following article.

https://blog.bitmex.com/the-mystery-of-the-bitcoin-nonce-pattern/

Answer (score 2):

It means randomness. In computing, if something a source of entropy means that means it is a source of randomness.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prepare a valid [block header](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm), transactions from the mempool should be selected, *merkle root* should be computed, *block version*, *previous block hash* and *difficulty* value should be filled. Finally, *time* should be set and with *nonce=0* hash calculations will start.

As far as I understand, what the author meant was: by incrementing *nonce* you continue to search for a valid hash, i.e. provide entropy. *nonce* is the fastest mechanism to try a new hash, until it maxes out.

Obviously, mining hardwares today uses mechanisms like *extraNonce* but it is a whole another issue.